# DatePickerDialog show previous year day

Tags: android, android-datepicker

My **`DatePickerDialog`** shows current date by default. Whenever moving past year on that time same **`DAY`**  is auto selecting. Does any guys meet this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void datePicker(Context ctx,final CommonEditTextRegular editText) {

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ctx, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                String myFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                editText.setText(sdf.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        fromDatePickerDialog.show();
        fromDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

Today is 9Th May 2019. When ever checking 2018 year.. 9Th May 2018 automatic select.

Comment: Are you sure you have selected date after moving year? there is no any issue in code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is how it works. It's not a bug. The Calendar is a Year based calendar.

When you change the year, a new whole year is generated and therefore a date is selected. by default, the same day/month as the previous one.